# Improve inefficient require in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently tried to get an `strace` sample of my app. A thing I notice is that when ruby try to require a file, it actually try to check the existence of the file in a lot of place. For example, this is what happen when it load `sprockets/processing`:

```
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.38.0/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/eventmachine-1.0.3/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/draper-1.3.1/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/request_store-1.0.8/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/devise-async-0.9.0/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thread_safe-0.3.3/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/orm_adapter-0.5.0/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job_active_record-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/dalli-2.7.0/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-rails-1.2.1/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cube-ruby-0.0.3/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cube-evaluator-0.0.1/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/css_parser-1.3.5/lib/sprockets/processing.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Apparently ruby/rails is examine every directory it could to find the correct place to request the file. I think this is extremely inefficient. Is there a way to improve over that?

Comment: in production all files are loaded so you dont get this kind of situation

Comment: This is what I got when running under production environment actually.

Comment: ok so its when you have constants defined `relatively`. Ruby has to do the constant lookup

Comment: I'm not getting you. So what we can do here?

Comment: if its your code, you can define constants in an absolute way, otherwise, nothing: constant lookup is part of Ruby

Comment: Right, I'm just thinking it would be more efficient for Ruby/Rails to build the index of files so it can do in memory look up instead of making multiple open call and relies on error until it found the file.

Comment: well lookup depends on the initial class you start it